# Google Translate Api and Special Characters

Tags: c#, google-translate

I've recently started using the google translate API inside a c# project.  I am trying to translate some text from english to french.  I am having issues with some special characters though.

For example the word Company comes thru as SociÃ©tÃ© instead of Société as it should.  Is there some way in code I can convert these to the correct special characters? ie (Ã© to é)

Thanks

If you need anymore info let me know.

Comment: I have a similar project, but the test app I am using is a Console app. The special characters look fine on the console. What specific technology are you using? WPF? WinForms?

Comment: You are most likely not dealing with the result string correctly.  Could it be a Ascii/UTF8/UTF16 issues.

Comment: It is WPF, maybe I will try a console app.

Very possible it could be an Ascii/UTF8/UTF16 issue, not one of my strong areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same exact issue.  If you're using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class to download the json response from google, try setting the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding.aspx) property to UTF8.

```
using(var webClient = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 })
{
    string json = webClient.DownloadString(someUri);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your problem, and it looks like you are using the UTF7 encoding. UTF8 is the way you need to go.

I use Google's API by creating a `WebRequest` to get an HTTP response from the server, then I read the response stream with a `StreamReader`. `StreamReader` defaults to UTF8, but to reproduce your problem, I passed `Encoding.UTF7` into the StreamReader's constructor.